# problem using flask-alchemy API post method doesn't work

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Trying to make my first web API, found code at some video, method that I wanna use to make a new user but first of all I need to login, in Postman I send get request basic auth, put the name and password and want to get the token, but get "Couldn't verify", why this happens, how can I fix it ?

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import uuid
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
import jwt
import datetime
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisissecret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///todo.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    public_id = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean)


class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(50))
    complete = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer)


def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = None

        if 'x-access-token' in request.headers:
            token = request.headers['x-access-token']

        if not token:
            return jsonify({'message' : 'Token is missing!'}), 401

        try: 
            data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
            current_user = User.query.filter_by(public_id=data['public_id']).first()
        except:
            return jsonify({'message' : 'Token is invalid!'}), 401

        return f(current_user, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorated

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    auth = request.authorization

    if not auth or not auth.username or not auth.password:
        return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login required!"'})

    user = User.query.filter_by(name=auth.username).first()

    if not user:
        return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login required!"'})

    if check_password_hash(user.password, auth.password):
        token = jwt.encode({'public_id' : user.public_id, 'exp' : datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)}, app.config['SECRET_KEY'])

        return jsonify({'token' : token.decode('UTF-8')})

    return make_response('Could not verify', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate' : 'Basic realm="Login required!"'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: are you sending the header in the request `x-access-token`

Comment: I don't know I just fill the body with name and password and send

Comment: the `x-access-token` looks like it should be something generated by your server and returned to the client for re-use. Make sure you include the header in your request and that is was a valid value given to you from the server.